# Delay before selecting text in macOS Safari?

Tags: safari

I do a lot of editing on Wikipedia, and as part of this, I often select copy/paste text around to reorganize it.

Sometime in the last month or so, I've noticed there is now a rather obvious delay before selecting text. Obvious as in 1 or 2 seconds.

This only seems to occur when you're not in an editor, but in a read-only field (like a wiki article)

And it only seems to happen once - after I have selected some text then it operates normally for a while. It re-starts again at some point but I can't say how long it takes.

Its almost as if the mouse went to sleep - but it didn't, the mouse is moving fine and I don't see anything like this in any other app - Smultron and xcode keep working fine for instance.

Is anyone else noticing this too?

Comment: Delays on websites are not necessarily an issue with macOS, but with the scripts being loaded on a web page.  The way you can verify this is by going to a different website and seeing if the delay exists there.

Comment: It is on every site. And it occurs after a time of inaction. It’s like it’s going into a low power mode or something. Clicking on another safari window and then back again clears it.

Comment: close down wikipedia and see if it continues.

Comment: I did and it occurred on this page. Again, any time I do not interact with a page, any page, it occurs.  I also notice it is not just selecting text, it also failed to respond to scrolling for the same amount of time.

Comment: I have the 100% the same issue. macOS Mojave + Safari on mac mini. Have you fixed it? I've noted that if I touch scroll wheel slightly I can make selection.

Comment: No solution. It does eventually work, it just takes a few seconds.

Comment: I created new account and there's no bug. I'm going to move all data there and check again.

Comment: So same machine, but a new user account? Next question: plugins.